# HoloEverywhere, ActionBarSherlock with Gradle gives 'Attribute xxx has already been defined'

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to migrate from Maven to Gradle with my project.

So far we used `HoloEverywhere v1.6.1` and `ABS v4.3.1` and with Maven everything worked fine.
Now I'm upgrading to `HoloEverywhere v2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` (latest master @ https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) and `ABS v4.4.0`

`HoloEverywhere` build.gradle is kept intact.

This is my project library `build.gradle` configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

    compile project(':contrib:holo-everywhere:library')
    compile project(':contrib:holo-everywhere:addons:slider')
    compile project(':contrib:holo-everywhere:addons:preferences')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Should I remove `ABS` here altogether because of new `support-v4:18.0.1` library?

Comment: I would recommend [ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html), instead of ABS... (fyi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Don't use ABS + HoloEverywhere v2.0.0+ together.

Comment: I think this it's the best answer. I've downloaded ABS and HE v2.0.0+ and not working. Thank You man!

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally checked the checkbox in Android Studio which adds the ActionBarCompact to the new project. Trying to add ABS gave me the same error. removing `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'` solves this issue.